# ng-grid delete and insert at the same time will not work

Tags: ng-grid

I want to delete a record and at the same time insert a new record:

```
                       scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData.splice(index, 1, result);
                        });
```

This is not working. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete solution for HTTP PUT RESTful ajax access and update ng-grid.

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: "/api/WebAPIService",
                data: $('#editForm').serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        var scope = angular.element($("#ngBody")).scope();
                        var row = scope.gridOptions.selectedItems[0];
                        var index = scope.myData.indexOf(row);
                        scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, false);
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData.splice(index, 1);   //delete a row from array
                        });
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            scope.myData.splice(index, 0, result);  //add a row to the same index
                        });
                        setTimeout(selectARow, 0);   //select the the newly added row
                        function selectARow() {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
                            });
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
```

The idea is we have to separate "delete" and "add". It looks more reasonable to put these 2 steps just in one statement like "scope.myData.splice(index, 1, result);". But as I tested, it simple does not work. Also we have to wrap "select item" in setTimeout to guarantee it is run after everything relating to "delete and add" was done.